# Can openWISP2 control the device WiFi adapter with the device guest openWRT on virtualbox?

Tags: openwisp

Is it possible for `openWISP2` to control a device's Wi-Fi adapter with an `openWRT` device guest on a virtual box?

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understood correctly:

- connect an OpenWRT VM on virtualbox to OpenWISP
- set up a template on OpenWISP which will reconfigure the wifi on the OpenWRT VM
- propagate this change to the machine which hosts the OpenWRT VM

If that's the case, I don't know, I don't think so, and even if it was possible, I wouldn't want to try to do it, it sounds like one of those things in which many steps can go wrong.

Did I understand correctly and if yes, why do you want to do that?